# Override interface instead of parent class in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I have a class that extends another class (`ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`) and also implements an interface(`myMessageProvider`) like this:

```
public class CustomMessageSource extends ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource implements myMessageProvider{

    @Override
    public String getMessage(String code, Object[] objects, final Locale locale{
        try {
            return getMessage(code, objects, locale);
        } catch (NoSuchMessageException e) {
            return code;
        }
    }
}
```

Both interface and parent class have `getMessage` function but I want to only override the interface one. Currently this code gives compile error because getMessage in the parent class (`ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`) is `final`.

Comment: do they take the same parameters? btw you are missing a ")" here`public String getMessage(String code, Object[] objects, final Locale locale{`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer, yes same parameters.

Comment: and are they supposed to do the same?

Comment: No, I have to override it so it does not throw `NoSuchMessageException` exception.

Comment: Create a different class that only implements `myMessageProvider`, and then use it and extend `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`.

Comment: well i just tried to reproduce the error you have with other classes but i don't get any error

Comment: @MarounMaroun, I need `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` in  the implementation.

Comment: How about overriding `getMessageInternal(String, Object[], Locale)` instead? According to [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractMessageSource.html#getMessage-org.springframework.context.MessageSourceResolvable-java.util.Locale-) it's called by the `getMessage()` methods and returns a `null` if not found. That `null` will then cause the exception to be thrown in the actual method, but instead of null you can return the code.

Comment: @Kayaman, that one works, but, I have to change whole project and change `getMessage` to `getMessageInternal`

Comment: @Arashsoft Why's that? It's called by the `getMessage()` methods, not your code (hence the name `Internal`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you override the `getMessageInternal()` method which is not `final`, and which is called *by* the `getMessage()` methods, you can affect the outcome by not returning a null. You do not need to change any calls to `getMessage()` methods in your code, as they will call the internal method themselves.

```
@Override
public String getMessageInternal(String code, Object[] objects, final Locale locale) {
        String foo = super.getMessageInternal(code, objects, locale);

        return foo == null ? code : foo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I got your idea which is nice! The only issue is because getMessage get called in the parent class, the child class override does not affect the parent class call.

Comment: @Arashsoft What on earth are you talking about. If you have an instance of `CustomMessageSource` and you call `getMessage()` on it, that method *will* be called.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, If I call `getMessage` on an instance of `customeMessageSource`. The `getMessage` of parrent class `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` handle the request. Inside that fucntion, it tries to call `getMessageInternal`. It is an internal call inside the `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`. It is not going to call the child override of it. (Maybe I am wrong?)

Comment: You are wrong. Since the `getMessageInternal` method is a `protected` method which is overridden in your implementation, the method of the instance (CustomMessageSource) is called. You can test it yourself by creating a class that has a method that calls `toString()`, extend it providing a different implementation of `toString()` and calling the original method. You'll notice that the overriding implementation is called.

Comment: It worked and the solution is so creative! :) Thank you very much.